# Is it "island of ###" or "island ###"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Should I write/say "Island of Guernsay", "Island of Madagascar", "Island of Taiwan", etc. or is it OK to write/say "Island Guernsay", "Island Taiwan", etc without "OF" as it is in German and Dutch?
(Sorry, English is not my native language)

Comment: There are some islands where _Island_ is part of the name, and comes after the other part: Staten Island, Holy Island. But I can't think of any where you'd use _Island_ before without _of_.

Answer (score 2):

It would be "Island of Guernsey", etc.

There are many cases where a name of the island ends with the word *island* as in "Long Island", "Vancouver Island", "Big Island". In these cases it's often considered incorrect or at least not quite as correct to use the "Island of" form.

There are some where it is acceptable to use both (the Island of Montreal is sometimes called "Montreal Island") and a few where the "Island of" form isn't just considered incorrect, but quite confusing ("Island of Big", "Island of Green" and "Island of Long").

Answer (score 0):

It would be "Island of Guernsay", "Island of Madagascar", "Island of Taiwan", etc.

Comment: That's "Guernsey"